# React Router v6 Redirects

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

thank you for taking the time to review this question in advance. I have experience with v5 but since changed pretty significantly in v6 I'm quite confused on how to setup a redirect within a nested page.

For example my page structure is as follows:

```
- /auth
- /client
  - dashboard
  - settings
    - profile
    - password
```

In my `/client` route i have a redirect set as follows (where `APP_URL = /client`:

```
<Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to={`${APP_URL}/dashboard`} />} />
```

However, within my `/settings` route i would like to have it so that `/settings` redirects to `/settings/profile`. When setting a redirect within a nested route that also has a redirect it appears to cause an endless loop or redirect to the redirect set within the parent.

**App.tsx**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="*" element={<Views />}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Views**

```
export const Views = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to={APP_URL} />} />
            <Route path={`${APP_URL}/*`} element={<AppLayout />} />
        </Routes>
    )
}
```

**AppLayout**

```
export const AppLayout = () => {
    return (
        <Content>
            <AppViews />
        </Content>
    )
}
```

**AppViews**

```
export const AppViews = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route
                path="/*"
                element={<Navigate to={`${APP_URL}/dashboard`} />}
            />
            <Route path={`/dashboard`} element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path={`/settings/*`} element={<Settings />} />
        </Routes>
    )
}
```

**Settings**

```
const Settings = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Routes>
                <Route
                    path="/*"
                    element={<Navigate to={`${APP_URL}/settings/profile`} />}
                />
                <Route path={`/profile`} element={<Profile />} />
                <Route path={`/password`} element={<Password />} />
            </Routes>
        </>
    )
}
```

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up absolute paths for relative paths. Since you are rendering `Settings` on a `"/settings"` path all the nested routes need to *also* be rendered as subroutes.

```
const Settings = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/*"  // "/"
          element={<Navigate to={`${APP_URL}/settings/profile`} />}
        />
        <Route path={`/profile`} element={<Profile />} />   // "/profile"
        <Route path={`/password`} element={<Password />} /> // "/password"
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}
```

Given:

```
<Route path="/settings/*" element={<Settings />} />
```

Using relative paths:

```
const Settings = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} />   // "/settings/profile"
        <Route path="password" element={<Password />} /> // "/settings/password"
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={<Navigate to="../profile" />}         // "/settings/profile"
        />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}
```

Using absolute paths:

```
const Settings = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={`/${APP_URL}/profile`} element={<Profile />} />   // "/settings/profile"
        <Route path={`/${APP_URL}/password`} element={<Password />} /> // "/settings/password"
        <Route
          path={`/${APP_URL}`}
          element={<Navigate to={`/${APP_URL}/profile`} />}  // "/settings/profile"
        />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: This is very informative thanks! Which type of path do you recommend?

Comment: Actually, i just changed it to relative pathing and it worked like a charm. You saved my day - THANK YOU!

Comment: @Nick Either should work equally well, but you just need to be aware of the routing used up to the nested component to use relative routing. Relative routing works well when you want to move the settings "group" around and the relative links will just work, but then you'd need to fix any absolute path links, etc...

Comment: And what if I need not only to redirect but also render common layout for parent route ( /settings in case of topic starter)?

Comment: @Mikenso This sounds like a great new SO post question. I suggest you create a new post for this and try to clarify what exactly you mean by "redirect but also render common layout for parent route". Redirect navigation actions are separate from UI/layout, so your question here doesn't make much sense to me currently. If you do create a new post feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can check when available.

Answer (score 0):

I believe route with asterisk should be put at the bottom to be fallback for routes that are not listed, lemme know this doesnt fix your issue

```
<Routes>
                <Route path={`/profile`} element={<Profile />} />
                <Route path={`/password`} element={<Password />} />
                <Route
                    path="/*"
                    element={<Navigate to={`${APP_URL}/settings/profile`} />}
                />
            </Routes>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still redirects to the one set in `AppViews`